# segmentation fault while writing to file

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

i am getting segmentation fault while writing data into file. here is code

```
 int arr[N]; // where N = 1508065

f = fopen( "datafile.txt", "w" );

if (f == NULL)

{

    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

for( i=1;i<=N;i++)

    {
       arr[i]=rand()%100;
       fprintf(f, "%d  %d  %d\n",i,1,arr[i] );
    } 

fclose(f);
```

I have tried with double arr[N] even then is a segmentation fault. It works fine when N is small.

Comment: You're reading past the end of the array.

Comment: You are likely blowing up you stack --> *STACK OVERFLOW* with an integer array of `1,508,065` integers or `6,032,260` bytes of data. Be careful. It may be wise to dynamically allocate that storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works fine when N is small.

I suppose you create `arr` as local variable, for `N = 1508065` it is more than 5 MB memory allocated onto stack - you got stack overflow. You should allocate `arr` using `malloc` function or create this array as global variable.

Problem with reading out of range was pointed out in previous answers.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. declaring it with malloc works fine. No segmentation fault even with for( i=1;i<=N;i++)

Comment: Change `i<=N` to `i < N`, you cannot read out of range - it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks I have changed it  to i < N

Answer (score 2):

`for( i=1;i<=N;i++)` will give undefined behavior.

C arrays start at 0 and go to N-1. Accessing element N is a no-no.

Should be `for( i=0;i<N;i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the `N`-th index of a N-size array is undefined behavior. You are accessing array out of bound. It will be `for( i = 1; i < N; i++)`.

From standard: [J.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) Under Undefined Behavior

> An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2)[7] given the declaration int a[4][5])

As you were using - arrays are `0` indexed in [c](/questions/tagged/c).